# Calling admin template controller function

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a menu in Magento admin:-

This is my code for rendering layout for magento admin:-

```html
<?php

class ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1_ExampleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    } 
}
```

Now what i want to do is I want to load a custom template file for this menu which is created or you can say I want to display content.

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to load a template file after hitting the controller.
Inside the layout folder where you have your custom files , inside the corresponding layout file you need to declare the .phtml file which is nothing a but a html file.

```
<frontname_example_index>
<reference name="content">
<block type="namespace_module/frontname" name="frontname"
            template="namespace/frontname/view.phtml" />
    </reference>
</frontname_example_index>
```